# How to sort a character vector where elements contain letters and numbers?

Tags: r, sorting, r-faq

I have a character array

```
cf <- c("V440","V457","V116","V327","V446","V108",
         "V155","V217","V120","V51","V477")
```

I would like to sort it in descending order so that I will have an output like this:

```
V51
V108
V116
V120
V155
V217
V327
V440
V446
V457
V477
```

I have tried `sort.list()` like this

```
cf[sort.list(cf)]
```

and got this answer:

```
[1] "V108" "V116" "V120" "V155" "V217" "V327" "V440" "V446" "V457" "V477" "V51"
```

and also tried `order()` and got same result.

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 80):

Try `mixedsort` from the "gtools" package:

```
> # install.packages("gtools") ## Uncomment if not already installed
> library(gtools)
> mixedsort(cf)
 [1] "V51"  "V108" "V116" "V120" "V155" "V217" "V327" "V440" "V446" "V457" "V477"
```

---

If you don't want to use `mixedsort` (not sure why one wouldn't), and if your vector has a pretty consistent pattern (eg letters followed by numbers), you can also probably try something like this. (Note: *Relatively untested.*)

```
newvec <- c("V440", "V457", "V116", "V327", "V446", "V108", "V155", 
            "V217", "V120", "V51", "V477", "B22", "A10", "Z01")

newvec[order(gsub("([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)", "\\1", newvec), 
             as.numeric(gsub("([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)", "\\2", newvec)))]
#  [1] "A10"  "B22"  "V51"  "V108" "V116" "V120" "V155" "V217" "V327" "V440"
# [11] "V446" "V457" "V477" "Z01"
```

Answer (score 64):

Plenty of right answers here, this is another way, just for fun.

```
cf[order(nchar(cf), cf)]
# [1] "V51"  "V108" "V116" "V120" "V155" "V217" "V327" "V440" "V446" "V457" "V477"
```

Comment: Well, this sorts c("ahoy", "hello", "hi") as "hi", "ahoy" and "hello" what is not exactly what a human would expect from a natural comparator

Answer (score 59):

One more solution in a line of code using `str_sort`function (from the  `stringr` packg.)

```
# install.packages("stringr") ## Uncomment if not already installed
library(stringr)
```

`str_sort(cf, numeric = TRUE)`

```
[1] "V51"  "V108" "V116" "V120" "V155" "V217" "V327" "V440" "V446" "V457" "V477"
```

Answer (score 13):

Just scrape off the preceding "V" character to build a sorting vector. No additional fancy tools required.

```
vals <- as.numeric(gsub("V","", cf))
cf[order(vals)]

[1] "V51"  "V108" "V116" "V120" "V155" "V217" "V327" "V440" "V446"
[10] "V457" "V477"
```

Answer (score 6):

R correctly orders strings alphabetically, that is why you get that result.

Aside from @Ananda very good answer, if you want to use base R you can use `strsplit` to remove the "V" from each string and then use `as.numeric` to cast the strings to integers:

```
vals <- as.numeric(sapply(cf, FUN=function(x){strsplit(x, "V")[[1]][2]}))
```

Now you can sort your strings using `vals`

```
cf[order(vals)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base approach utilizing `names` and `sort` (Ananda's was pretty slick):

```
cf <- c("V440","V457","V116","V327","V446","V108",
         "V155","V217","V120","V51","V477")

cf2 <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", cf))
names(cf2) <- seq_along(cf2)
cf[as.numeric(names(sort(cf2)))]

## > cf[as.numeric(names(sort(cf2)))]
##  [1] "V51"  "V108" "V116" "V120" "V155" "V217" "V327"
##  [8] "V440" "V446" "V457" "V477"
```