# Re-arrange rows on dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

Say I have:

```
#Continuous variable 1
x1<-rnorm(15, 1, .5)
#Continuous Variable 2
x2<-rnorm(15,1,.5)
#Sample Names
s.names<-c("S3","S5","S8","S14","S11","S13","S15","S12","S10","S2","S1","S6","S7","S4","S9")

df.temp<-data.frame(s.names,x1,x2)

df.temp
   s.names        x1        x2
1       S3 0.7025583 1.6616103
2       S5 0.4401055 1.5715047
3       S8 1.3691886 0.7754010
4      S14 1.1365712 1.2697196
5      S11 2.1193612 0.5968068
6      S13 0.6834145 1.4669863
7      S15 0.7050808 1.3287179
8      S12 2.0293910 0.7502497
9      S10 0.6807918 1.0793561
10      S2 0.6809873 0.7454851
11      S1 0.3775086 0.3150030
12      S6 2.1235465 1.4864190
13      S7 1.1657259 1.3279573
14      S4 1.4629794 0.6146412
15      S9 0.6916639 0.4507309
```

Now let us try and order.

```
df.temp[order(df.temp$s.names),]
   s.names        x1        x2
11      S1 0.3775086 0.3150030
9      S10 0.6807918 1.0793561
5      S11 2.1193612 0.5968068
8      S12 2.0293910 0.7502497
6      S13 0.6834145 1.4669863
4      S14 1.1365712 1.2697196
7      S15 0.7050808 1.3287179
10      S2 0.6809873 0.7454851
1       S3 0.7025583 1.6616103
14      S4 1.4629794 0.6146412
2       S5 0.4401055 1.5715047
12      S6 2.1235465 1.4864190
13      S7 1.1657259 1.3279573
3       S8 1.3691886 0.7754010
15      S9 0.6916639 0.4507309
```

But my issue is I have trouble now manipulating the data frame.  In particular, when I try and order or sort the s.names it always returns something along the lines of >S1,S10,S11,S12...,S2,S20,S21,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7 etc. (not 21 samples but see above example.)   The reason is, of course, I am trying to re-arrange the data frame by rows.  order() and sort() have had issues with this.

Additionally, I am wondering, if I want to "bootstrap" or randomly change the rows around for statistical reasonssamples linked to each other as in S1 will have a corresponding x1 and x2 value, it will just be in a different, perhaps random order e.g. S5,S11,S6, etc.

My end goal is to do regression such as ANOVA(), cov() and cor()

EDIT: Added more code

Comment: Don't use `cbind`; use `data.frame`, like `data.frame(s.names,x1,x1)`. `cbind` makes a matrix and matrices all have the same data type (character in this case, which is sorted lexicographically).

Comment: s.names is a vector.  You can check this by using is.vector(s.names) Additionally, I not as interesting in sorting by alphabetical order, but more so again interesting in re-arranging the ROWS of the data frame for analysis.  Read the full paragraph.  The issue regarding numerical ordering/sorting is occuring (I can easily get rid of the "S" if I wanted to by using the substr() function)

Comment: Still get the same issue above as when used the link from alexforrence

Comment: Based on the edits, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531403/how-to-sort-a-character-vector-where-elements-contain-letters-and-numbers-in-r might be closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused because you're trying to sort by a string column as if it was a numeric column. If all the elements begin with `S`, you can just make them numeric:

```
> x <- paste0("S", 1:20)
> x
 [1] "S1"  "S2"  "S3"  "S4"  "S5"  "S6"  "S7"  "S8"  "S9"  "S10" "S11" "S12" "S13" "S14" "S15" "S16" "S17" "S18"
[19] "S19" "S20"
> sort(x)
 [1] "S1"  "S10" "S11" "S12" "S13" "S14" "S15" "S16" "S17" "S18" "S19" "S2"  "S20" "S3"  "S4"  "S5"  "S6"  "S7" 
[19] "S8"  "S9" 
> x2 <- sort(x)
> x2 <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", x2))
> sort(x2)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

If you don't want to remove the leading `S`, you can use `order()` on the extracted numbers like this:

```
> x[order(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", x)))]
```

Or in this example

```
> x[order(x2)]
```

Both result in

```
 [1] "S1"  "S2"  "S3"  "S4"  "S5"  "S6"  "S7"  "S8"  "S9"  "S10" "S11" "S12" "S13" "S14" "S15" "S16" "S17" "S18"
[19] "S19" "S20"
```

Your *Additionally* isn't very clear, but if it's a different problem you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as @Molx, this time with a different function:

`df.temp[order(as.numeric(substr(df.temp$s.names,2,3))),]`

With your data should give you what you want. The problem is you're trying to sort strings, and they will do in alphabetical (not numerical) order.

Answer (score 0):

`gtools` package:

```
library(gtools)
df.temp[mixedorder(df.temp$s.names), ]
```

Another base alternative:

```
n <- df.temp$s.names[order(as.numeric((gsub("S", "", df.temp$s.names))))] 
df.temp[match(n, df.temp$s.names), ]
```

Output:

```
   s.names         x1          x2
11      S1  1.2285667  1.48669700
10      S2  0.9438498  0.01775496
1       S3  1.3671933  1.66880402
14      S4  0.7718479  1.53751408
2       S5  0.6023717  0.94600954
12      S6 -0.1341811  1.17744773
13      S7  1.1150349 -0.24347135
3       S8  0.3934848  0.90117148
15      S9  1.7059979  1.64684407
9      S10  0.7533375  1.05615732
5      S11  0.6980853  0.46164739
8      S12  0.3826094  1.26324581
6      S13  0.9616772  1.58527306
4      S14 -0.1876272  1.05792541
7      S15  1.4213483  0.96066296
```

`sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT *, 
      ltrim([s.names],'S') AS n
      FROM [df.temp] ORDER BY n*1")
```

Output:

```
   s.names         x1          x2  n
1       S1  1.2285667  1.48669700  1
2       S2  0.9438498  0.01775496  2
3       S3  1.3671933  1.66880402  3
4       S4  0.7718479  1.53751408  4
5       S5  0.6023717  0.94600954  5
6       S6 -0.1341811  1.17744773  6
7       S7  1.1150349 -0.24347135  7
8       S8  0.3934848  0.90117148  8
9       S9  1.7059979  1.64684407  9
10     S10  0.7533375  1.05615732 10
11     S11  0.6980853  0.46164739 11
12     S12  0.3826094  1.26324581 12
13     S13  0.9616772  1.58527306 13
14     S14 -0.1876272  1.05792541 14
15     S15  1.4213483  0.96066296 15
```