# Sort a dataframe based on a character column containing letters followed by numbers in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a dataframe like this

```
Day <- c("Day1","Day20","Day5","Day10")
A <- c (5,7,2,0)
B <- c(15,12,16,30)

df <- data.frame(Day,A,B)

df$Day <- as.character(df$Day)
```

The first column is a character and hence I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531403/how-to-sort-a-character-vector-where-elements-contain-letters-and-numbers-in-r) to sort this dataframe but not quite getting it right since this only sorts the first column and leaves the column 2 & 3 unchanged.

```
df$Day <- df$Day[order(nchar(df$Day), df$Day)]
```

**My desired output is**

```
 Day A  B
Day1 5 15
Day5 2 16
Day10 0 30
Day20 7 12
```

What am I missing here? Kindly provide some inputs.

Comment: Try this instead: `df <- df[order(nchar(df$Day)), ]`. Or simply `df <- df[order(df$Day), ]` if you don't want to sort by length. This does string sorting. If you want a different ordering, you are better off sorting by the numeric component of that column.

Comment: Not right. Day20 comes before Day10.

Comment: Like I said, you can't use strings to order and expect numeric ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using something like this that does numeric day sorting:

```
Day <- c("Day1","Day20","Day5","Day10")
A <- c (5,7,2,0)
B <- c(15,12,16,30)
df <- data.frame(Day,A,B, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$DayNum <- as.numeric(gsub('Day', '', df$Day))
df <- df[order(df$DayNum), ]
```

Output as follows:

```
df
    Day A  B DayNum
1  Day1 5 15      1
3  Day5 2 16      5
4 Day10 0 30     10
2 Day20 7 12     20
```

You can avoid creating a new column by doing the following (was trying to show full detail of what was going on):

```
df <- df[order(as.numeric(substr(df$Day, 4, nchar(df$Day)))), ]
```

Output will be same as above.

Comment: Yes. Perfect. I was trying to work out after you told me. Thanks for posting this. So elegantly done. I just applied it to a bigger dataset that I have and its fast.

Comment: I updated with a line that avoids adding a column. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with `mixedorder` from `library(gtools)`

```
 library(gtools)
 df[mixedorder(df$Day),]
 #    Day A  B
 #1  Day1 5 15
 #3  Day5 2 16
 #4 Day10 0 30
 #2 Day20 7 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Day <- c("Day1","Day20","Day5","Day10")
A <- c (5,7,2,0)
B <- c(15,12,16,30)
df <- data.frame(Day,A,B, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# add leading zero(s) to digits in values of Day column, 
# e.g., "Day5" --> "Day05"
# then return the indices of the sorted vector
indices_to_sort_by <- sort(
    sub(
        pattern = "([a-z]{1})([1-9]{1}$)", 
        replacement = "\\10\\2", 
        x = df$Day
    ), 
    index.return = TRUE)$ix 

df[indices_to_sort_by, ]
#     Day A  B
# 1  Day1 5 15
# 3  Day5 2 16
# 4 Day10 0 30
# 2 Day20 7 12
```