# Rearranging character vectors in a row of a matrix

Tags: r

Suppose `M` has the following structure:-

```
> dput(head(M))
structure(list(SV = structure(c(38L, 21L, 24L, 20L, 54L, 45L), .Label = c("X1 X2 X3", 
"X1 X2 X3 X10 X6 X9", "X1 X2 X3 X10 X8 X9", "X1 X2 X3 X10 X9 X8", 
"X1 X2 X3 X4", "X1 X2 X3 X4 X9 X7", "X1 X2 X3 X5", "X1 X2 X3 X5 X10", 
"X1 X2 X3 X5 X6 X4", "X1 X2 X3 X5 X9", "X1 X2 X3 X6", "X1 X2 X3 X6 X7", 
"X1 X2 X3 X7", "X1 X2 X3 X7 X8 X10", "X1 X2 X3 X8", "X1 X2 X3 X8 X4", 
"X1 X2 X3 X8 X9 X10 X7", "X1 X2 X3 X9", "X1 X2 X3 X9 X10", "X1 X2 X3 X9 X5", 
"X2 X1 X3", "X2 X1 X3 X10", "X2 X1 X3 X10 X5", "X2 X1 X3 X10 X9", 
"X2 X1 X3 X4", "X2 X1 X3 X4 X10", "X2 X1 X3 X4 X6", "X2 X1 X3 X4 X8", 
"X2 X1 X3 X5 X10 X4", "X2 X1 X3 X5 X4", "X2 X1 X3 X5 X7", "X2 X1 X3 X6", 
"X2 X1 X3 X6 X5 X7", "X2 X1 X3 X6 X8", "X2 X1 X3 X6 X8 X9", "X2 X1 X3 X7", 
"X2 X1 X3 X7 X10", "X2 X1 X3 X7 X4", "X2 X1 X3 X7 X5", "X2 X1 X3 X7 X9 X5", 
"X2 X1 X3 X8", "X2 X1 X3 X8 X10 X4", "X2 X1 X3 X8 X10 X5 X9", 
"X2 X1 X3 X8 X6", "X2 X1 X3 X9", "X2 X1 X3 X9 X5", "X2 X1 X3 X9 X5 X4", 
"X2 X1 X3 X9 X6 X7 X10", "X2 X1 X3 X9 X7", "X2 X3 X1 X5 X6", 
"X2 X3 X1 X8", "X3 X1 X2", "X3 X2 X1", "X3 X2 X1 X4"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It can be seen that in some rows they are not consecutive. I need the appearance in a consecutive order `X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7` in this order. 
How can I rearrange the rows of `M`

Comment: Please share an example of `M`

Comment: how can I share from RStudio ?

Comment: Just use `dput(head(M))` and copy/paste the output in your question

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly with the exact structure of ```M```. I need the elements of row to appear in a systematic manner ..first X1, then X2, X3, X4 etc....

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but very closely related: [How to sort a character vector where elements contain letters and numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17531403/903061)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split, strip the numbers and order, i.e.

```
M$SV <- sapply(M$SV, function(i){i1 <- strsplit(as.character(i), ' ')[[1]];  
                                 i2 <- i1[order(as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', i1)))]; 
                                 paste(i2, collapse = ' ')})
```

which gives,

> ```
>                SV
> 1  X1 X2 X3 X4 X7
> 2        X1 X2 X3
> 3 X1 X2 X3 X9 X10
> 4  X1 X2 X3 X5 X9
> 5     X1 X2 X3 X4
> 6     X1 X2 X3 X9
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
M$SV <- as.character(M$SV)
M$SV <- sapply(
  strsplit(M$SV, " "),
  function(x) {
    y <- x[order(as.integer(sub("X", "", x, fixed = TRUE)))]
    paste(y, collapse = " ")
  }
)
M


#                SV
# 1  X1 X2 X3 X4 X7
# 2        X1 X2 X3
# 3 X1 X2 X3 X9 X10
# 4  X1 X2 X3 X5 X9
# 5     X1 X2 X3 X4
# 6     X1 X2 X3 X9
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as mine essentially?

Comment: I guess, just different flavour. I think mine should be faster.

Comment: It should since you are not splitting each line

Answer (score 0):

try this using transponse and apply:

```
M <- data.frame(a=c("z1","z1"),
                b=c("z5","z4"),
                c=c("z2","z3"),
                d=c("z6","z2"))

>t(apply(M, 1, sort))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "z1" "z2" "z5" "z6"
[2,] "z1" "z2" "z3" "z4"
```

Comment: how can I do it for 2 different rows? and what does 1 mean in the apply function ?

Comment: This will miss-sort when the numbers go above 9. See `sort(c("X1", "X2", "X10", "X11"))`.