# How to sort data.frame by columns with strings containing different number of digits?

Tags: r

I would like to sort a df like this one:

```r
library(dplyr)
tags <- c("F23-F45", "A69-1008-1", "A69-1008-10", "A69-1008-10", "A69-1008-100", "A69-1008-12")
animal_names <- c("Dim","Dami", "Pet", "Nic", "Li", "Tan")

df <- tibble(tag = tags, animal_name = animal_names)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  tag          animal_name
  <chr>        <chr>      
1 F23-F45      Dim        
2 A69-1008-1   Dami       
3 A69-1008-10  Pet        
4 A69-1008-10  Nic        
5 A69-1008-100 Li         
6 A69-1008-12  Tan
```

I would like to sort first by `tag` and then by `animal_name`. Typically I do it with `arrange()`function of dplyr package. It would result in this df:

```r
> df %>% arrange(tag, animal_name)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  tag          animal_name
  <chr>        <chr>      
1 A69-1008-1   Dami       
2 A69-1008-10  Nic        
3 A69-1008-10  Pet        
4 A69-1008-100 Li         
5 A69-1008-12  Tan        
6 F23-F45      Dim
```

However, I would like to apply a kind of numeric sort so that `A69-1008-12` occurrs **before** `A69-1008-100`. This problem has been solved for a vector already (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531403/how-to-sort-a-character-vector-where-elements-contain-letters-and-numbers-in-r)) but I wonder how to transfer it to data.frames?

Answer (score 5):

In [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_order.html) 1.5 you can use `arrange(df, str_rank(x,nummeric=T))`

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/59730594:

This can be done with `arrange()` by converting `df$tag` to a **factor** first, with **levels** in a predefined order:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Create a vector of tags in the desired order
sorted_tags <-
  df %>%
  distinct(tag) %>%        # Unique tags only
  pull() %>%               # Convert to vector
  str_sort(numeric = TRUE) # Sort as numeric values
sorted_tags
#[1] "A69-1008-1"   "A69-1008-10"  "A69-1008-12"  "A69-1008-100" "F23-F45"

# Sort the df with arrange(), but use tag as a factor with sorted_tags as levels
df %>%
  arrange(
    factor(tag, levels = sorted_tags),
    animal_name
  )
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  tag          animal_name
#  <chr>        <chr>      
#1 A69-1008-1   Dami       
#2 A69-1008-10  Nic        
#3 A69-1008-10  Pet        
#4 A69-1008-12  Tan        
#5 A69-1008-100 Li         
#6 F23-F45      Dim
```

Answer (score 1):

Package `stringr`'s sorting functions have an argument `numeric` that when set to `TRUE` sort the data numerically, even if they are mixed character/numeric data.

```
i <- stringr::str_order(df$tag, numeric = TRUE)
df[i, ]
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  tag          animal_name
#  <chr>        <chr>      
#1 A69-1008-1   Damiano    
#2 A69-1008-10  Nico       
#3 A69-1008-10  Peter      
#4 A69-1008-100 Tanja      
#5 A69-1008-12  Lien
```

## Edit

To answer to the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631764/how-to-sort-data-frame-by-columns-with-strings-containing-different-number-of-di/63632289?noredirect=1#comment112523951_63632289) asking for what already is in the question (my emphasis),

> Yes, this is what I first tried and it works great with vectors, but
> **how to order a data.frame by `tag` AND `animal_name`** using `str_sort`?

the following `dplyr` pipe will solve the problem. The trick is to note that `str_order` will produce an order vector with no ties, even if they are present in the input vector. This will make a second column irrelevant. Therefore, the code groups by the input vector `tag`, then `mutate`s the order vector `i` making each group equal to its first element. And now the dataframe can be sorted with `arrange`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(i = stringr::str_order(df$tag, numeric = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(tag) %>%
  mutate(i = first(i)) %>%
  arrange(i, animal_name) %>%
  select(-i)
## A tibble: 5 x 2
## Groups:   tag [4]
#  tag          animal_name
#  <chr>        <chr>      
#1 A69-1008-1   Damiano    
#2 A69-1008-10  Nico       
#3 A69-1008-10  Peter      
#4 A69-1008-12  Tanja      
#5 A69-1008-100 Lien
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I first tried and it works great with vectors, but how to order a data.frame by `tag` AND `animal_name` using `str_sort`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `gtools::mixedorder` doesn't seem to give expected output in this case.

Here is an alternative by removing all non-numeric values from `tag` and ordering the data.

In base R, we can do :

```
df[with(df, order(as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', tag)), animal_name)), ]
```

The same can be used in `arrange` as well :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(order(as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', tag))), animal_name)

#  tag          animal_name
#  <chr>        <chr>      
#1 A69-1008-1   Damiano    
#2 A69-1008-10  Peter      
#3 A69-1008-10  Nico       
#4 A69-1008-12  Tanja      
#5 A69-1008-100 Lien
```

Comment: `gtools::mixedorder` is good for vectors, but how to using it for sorting data.frames by multiple columns? The solution with `as.numeric` would not work in general case where tag column contains tags with not only different digits but also different characters.

Comment: I guess `mixedorder` doesn't work because of double `"-"` here. Can you update your post with sample of your actual data? I guess we have to use some sort of regex to achieve the desired output.

Comment: I updated the post adding a case where tag has different syntax. The case shown in example is actual data. I just removed not relevant columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my answer actually. I could achieve what I wanted by using function `mixedsortDF` from [`jamba` package](https://github.com/jmw86069/jamba/):

```r
mixedSortDF(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  tag          animal_name
  <chr>        <chr>      
1 A69-1008-1   Dami       
2 A69-1008-10  Nic        
3 A69-1008-10  Pet        
4 A69-1008-12  Tan        
5 A69-1008-100 Li         
6 F23-F45      Dim
```

The only drawback is that if `df` has more columns and you want to order by a subset of them, you cannot provide column names but only column numbers:

```r
df$extra <- c(1,3,5,4,10,3)
sort_by <- c("animal_name", "tag")
library(purrr)
sort_by_col_numbers <- map_dbl(sort_by, ~which(colnames(df) %in% .)) # to get column numbers always in right order

mixedSortDF(df, byCols = sort_by_col_numbers)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  tag          animal_name extra
  <chr>        <chr>       <dbl>
1 A69-1008-1   Dami            3
2 F23-F45      Dim             1
3 A69-1008-100 Li             10
4 A69-1008-10  Nic             4
5 A69-1008-10  Pet             5
6 A69-1008-12  Tan             3
```