# ggplot: order x axis in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting my data in ggplot and am trying to order x-axis of my plot but it doesn't work and I cant understand why.
Here is my data
test.txt

```
V1  V2     Count
a   a1b15   2
a   a1b8    7
a   a3b9    9
a   u1b10   11
a   a2b19   2
b   a5b12   1
b   a1b13   5
b   a1b14   10
b   a1b17   15
c   a1b16   16
c   a1b17   17
a   a1b18   5
a   a2b11   10
d   a1b20   15
d   a1b25   16
plotd<-read.table("test.txt", header=TRUE)
ggplot(plotd,aes(x=fct_relevel(V2, "u1b10","a1b13","a1b14","a1b15","a1b16","a1b17","a1b17","a1b18","a1b20","a1b25","a1b8","a2b11","a2b19","a3b9","a5b12"), y=V1)) + 
       geom_tile(aes(fill=Count),  width=0.3) + 
       geom_text(aes(label = Count), data=cbind(aggregate(Count~V1, plotd, sum), V1="Total"), size=10) + 
        geom_text(aes(label = Count), data=cbind(aggregate(Count~V2, plotd, sum), V2="Total"), size=10) + 
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "dark red") + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), text=element_text(size=30)) + 
        scale_y_discrete(name="test", limits = rev(c(unique(as.character(plotd$V1)), 'Total')))+
        scale_x_discrete(limits = c(unique(plotd$V2), "Total")) + 
        labs(x="Med", fill ="Count", Title= "med-test") +
        geom_text(aes(label=plotd$Count), size=8)
```

Comment: The issue is that you relevel the factor "on the fly" (within `aes()`, not assigning the change to the data frame), but in other layers you specifically refer back to the `plotd` data frame which is still in the default order. Use `plotd$V2 <- fct_relevel(plotd$V2, ...)` as a separate step before plotting, and I think it should work.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to type out all those levels, there are functions like `gtool::mixedsort()` that will generate that ordering for you. [See this FAQ for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17531403/903061).

Comment: Oh---one more issue - `scale_x_discrete(limits = c(unique(plotd$V2), "Total"))` is explicitly setting the axis breaks in the reverse order that they appear in the data frame. Use the same order there (and if you use it there, you don't really need it anywhere else)

Comment: plotd$V2 <- fct_relevel(plotd$V2, ...)-Doesnt work. Removing the scale_x_discrete would solve the problem BUT will not always place the "total" at the very end.

Comment: I edited the data file to reflect the change.

Comment: scale_x_discrete(limits = c(unique(plotd$V2), "u1b10","a1b13","a1b14","a1b15","a1b16","a1b17","a1b17","a1b18","a1b20","a1b25","a1b8","a2b11","a2b19","a3b9","a5b12", "Total")) does work .BUT this all is pushed to the right side of the plot while the still contains the default order on the left (empty tiles)

Comment: Get rid of the `unique(plotd$V2)` in your limits if you explicitly write them out. `scale_x_discrete(limits = c("u1b10","a1b13","a1b14","a1b15","a1b16","a1b17","a1b17","a1b18","a1b20","a1b25","a1b8","a2b11","a2b19","a3b9","a5b12", "Total"))`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks